# Fire the Row Source (Pass through) query on request (Not on Load)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2016

I am developing an application using MS access 2016. In my form I have a list with   a "Pass-Through" query as the row source.

The pass through query is fired when on load the form. But I want to load/display the data in the list only when the user request (button click). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am using SQL Server query in "Pass-Through" query (via ODBC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the RowSource of the listbox empty initially.

Fill it when the user clicks the button.

Comment: What happens if the user use the application again.? Will the RowSource be filled.?

Comment: That should not happen. If in doubt, set `RowSource = ""` in the _OnOpen_ event.

Comment: This Worked. Thanks